# Calling PHP function when clicking on HTML

Tags: php, html

I have the following menu in my HTML code (index.php):

```
            <ul class="clear-bullet">
              <li><a href="calendario.php">Visão Geral</a></li>
              <li><a href="cadastros.php">Cadastrar Funcionário</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar Funcionários</a></li>
              <li><a href="cad_salao.php">Cadastrar Salão</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List Salons</a></li> <!-- wsListSalons($token)-->
              <li><a href="cad_servico.php">Cadastrar Serviço</a></li>
              <li><a href="cad_categoria_servico.php">Cadastrar Categoria de Serviço</a></li>
              <li><a href="cad_produto.php">Cadastrar Produto</a></li>
              <li><a href="cad_categoria_produto.php">Cadastrar Categoria de Produto</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
            </ul>
```

My issue is: I wanna call a function named "wsListSalons" from other .php file (rest.php) when click on >List Salons< from my menu. How can I do this without using AJAX? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to POST to the other script and return. This would cause your page to refresh. Why do you want to do this without AJAX?

Comment: your function is on that page (rest.php) only or on other page.And also is it normal function or a function present inside a class?

Comment: too many ways to do this. GET, POST method?

Comment: not possible. PHP runs on the server. HTML is markup that is rendered on the client. It is not a programming language and cannot "call" anything. You can, however, use a link (e.g. `<a href="...">`) or javascript (ajax request) to trigger an HTTP request to the server and have your php code run at that point.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh my function is only on rest.php and is a normal function. It is outside a class.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you show me one way to do this using GET? Thank you.

Comment: So just give the link in href, but if you want to do it without page refresh and without going to that page then ajax is only option.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh what kind of link in this case? i tried href="wsListSalons($token)" and it was not found.

Comment: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for the reading, but i'm afraid this does not work with functions.

Comment: sure it does, you just need to use `isset()` and call the function.

Comment: I've posted an answer you can look at below, if that's what the question is about.

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh, you *have* to use AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

If this is what I understood from the question and as the OP stated in comments, they would like to use a GET method:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['get_function'])){

// echo "Optional.";

wsListSalons(); // this calls the function when set/clicked on

}

function wsListSalons() {

   echo "Calling the function worked!";

}

?>

<li><a href="?get_function">List Salons</a></li>
```

---

**Sidenote:**

- Using `?get_function` will call the current file. If you want to use the function in another file, you will need to use `other_file.php?get_function` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it is using ajax. If you don't want to use it you can use Java but it don't suggest you doing it.

Other way to do it is you click on "List Salons" linking to "rest.php", it does wsListSalons function and you redirect to the page the visitor was in:

```
function wsListSalons(){...}
header("Location: index.php");
```